# postgres loop record retrieval syntax error

Tags: postgresql, loops, syntax-error

I've got this loop which throws an error:

> SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "."   Position: 435

```
DO
$$DECLARE
declare 
s_row record;
sch cursor for
SELECT  distinct n.nspname as "schema"
FROM pg_catalog.pg_class c
LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace
WHERE pg_catalog.array_to_string(c.relacl, E'\n') LIKE '%user123%';
begin
    open sch;
    loop
    fetch sch into s_row;
    exit when not found;
    REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA s_row.schema FROM partner_reporting_user3_to_delete;
    end loop;
close sch;
END;$$;
```

I thought I could reference the record row content by just saying `s_row.schema` but I'm missing something here..

Answer (score 0):

Try dynamic SQL for that.

```
...
EXECUTE format('REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA %I FROM partner_reporting_user3_to_delete;', s_row.schema);
...
```